# Node.js ReadableStream: what is chunk size?

Tags: node.js

Let's look at the following code snippet:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const server = require('http').createServer();

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  const src = fs.createReadStream('./big.file');
  src.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(8000);
```

fs.createReadStream divides the content of big.file to chunks and reads the file "chunk after chunk".

My question is what is the size of every chunk, where it's defined and how I can change the chunk size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is how to change the chunk size

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar', { highWaterMark: 128 * 1024 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation for `createReadStream` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options).

It takes in an `options` object as its second parameter.

`highWaterMark` is the option that you are looking for, and it defaults to `64 * 1024`.

Comment: This documentation is for Node v0.3.1, this is not a valid option in versions of Node currently in LTS.